# AngularJS giving errror as module not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In one file i have created module & controller as

```
var module = angular.module('app', []);
module.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, ContactService)
```

Then in second file i created service

```
module.service('ContactService', function ($http)
```

And included this service file in Main controller file. But getting error as module not defined and service not defined.

Comment: DId you correctly import all your .JS files in index.html ?

Comment: You don't need to include service file in controller file, you need to include both in index.html

Comment: post your code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Try to give some different name while defining the module. Also make sure that you have inserted the module in the HTML.That is for example,

```
    <html ng-app="your module definition name here">
```

Comment: Did you try changing your module definition name?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global variable for `angular.module`

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('ContactController', function ($scope, ContactService);

angular.module('app').service('ContactService', function ($http);
```

Only first time you need second argument in `angular.module`.

Comment: have you defined `ng-app="app"` in your html?

Comment: name wiil be same in `ng-app` and `angular.module` first argument

Comment: now what error are you facing, because `module` variable is not any more in your application

Comment: same error message... service not defined and module not defined

Comment: I told you don't use `module` variable, then why same error?

Comment: I think you forget to remove some of `module` variable from your application, error will show you file name and line number